# Are there health consequences if I don't spay my cat?

Tags: cats, health, surgery

I'm thinking of spaying my cat sense most people suggest I do so. But I'm still not convinced about why I should do that. My cat doesn't have behaviour issues, she acts like a normal cat would, she's nice to humans and doesn't like cats alot, except when she's ready for mating. I'd like her to have kittens at some point in her life and I'd love to help take care of them. People still ask me to spay and say it's better if done.

So my question is, why is spaying that important if you agree to let your cat have kittens and are welling to take care of them? Are there health consequences for not spaying your cat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be health consequences. For instance,  your cat could end up with pyometra, which is an infection of the uterus that tends to happen in unspayed cats that do not end up getting pregnant. https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/pyometra-in-cats There are probably other conditions that are prevented by spaying also.